# How to get Paypal transaction Id after getting paykey in paypal integration in iphone?

Tags: iphone, transactions, paypal, response, paykey

I am going to implement paypal in my iphone native app. But I am facig an issue in that.

I want to get my transaction Id regarding my PayKey. There is a direct method to get pay key in PayPal library to get PayKey but not a method to get **transactionId**.

Here is that method:

```
-(void)paymentSuccessWithKey:(NSString *)payKey andStatus:(PayPalPaymentStatus)paymentStatus;
```

As I am thinking IPN(Instant Payment Notification ) can help to resolve this issue but I don't know how to implement that one in my app?

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks,
Chandra Prakash

Comment: Are you using this for in App purchases? I would check with Apple's policy on that before I went any further as they have their own in app purchase mechanism.

Comment: I am developing an app from where ou members can purchase event passes for their purpose. And pay through Paypal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fianlly I have got solution of my question.

I have got transaction Id using IPN.

When I selected **ENABLE IPN** Option from my PayPal account then all details send by paypal I have received on URL which I given from there I have got all required fields.

Here are a few links to help you

IPN Overview:
https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/howto_html_instantpaymentnotif

IPN Documentation:
https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/IPNGuide.pdf

IPN Variables:
https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_IPNandPDTVariables

IPN Script Example:
https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?&cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_admin_IPNImplementation

IPN Script Generator:
https://www.paypaltech.com/SG2/

Thanks,
Cp

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue but was unable to rely on IPN so I thought I would share another method.

you don't need to use IPN, you can get the transaction ID with the payKey, which is useful for verifying mobile payments. Here is a php block that will get all of the transaction information from a payKey. You'll need to call it from your mobile app. For iOS you could use this tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/13511/how-to-create-an-app-like-instagram-with-a-web-service-backend-part-12

```
<?
header("Content-Type: application/json");

//DEBUG TO CHECK PAYKEY
//turn php errors on
ini_set("track_errors", true);

//Example payKey (got from iOS app)
$payKey = "<snip>";

//set PayPal Endpoint to sandbox
$url = trim("https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/PaymentDetails?payKey=".$payKey."&requestEnvelope.errorLanguage=en_US");

//PayPal API Credentials

//to do: change these for production credentials in the production app
$API_UserName = "<snip>";
$API_Password = "<snip>";
$API_Signature = "<snip>";

//Default App ID for Sandbox
$API_AppID = "APP-80W284485P519543T";

$API_RequestFormat = "NV";
$API_ResponseFormat = "NV";

try
{
    //Create payload for this query
    $bodyparams = array ("requestEnvelope.errorLanguage" => "en_US");
    // convert payload array into url encoded query string
    $body_data = http_build_query($bodyparams, "", chr(38));   // Generates body data

    //create request and add headers
    $params = array("http" => array(
        "method" => "POST",
        "content" => $body_data,
        "header" =>  "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID: " . $API_UserName . "\r\n" .
        "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD: " . $API_Password . "\r\n" .
        "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE: " . $API_Signature . "\r\n" .
        "X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID: " . $API_AppID . "\r\n" .
        "X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT: " . $API_RequestFormat . "\r\n" .
        "X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT: " . $API_ResponseFormat
));


    //create stream context
    $ctx = stream_context_create($params);

    //open the stream and send request
    $fp = @fopen($url, "r", false, $ctx);

    //get response
    $response = stream_get_contents($fp);

    //check to see if stream is open
    if ($response === false) {
        throw new Exception("php error message = " . "$php_errormsg");
    }

    //close the stream
    fclose($fp);

    //parse the ap key from the response

    $keyArray = explode("&", $response);

    foreach ($keyArray as $rVal){
        list($qKey, $qVal) = explode ("=", $rVal);
        $kArray[$qKey] = $qVal;
    }

    //print the response to screen for testing purposes
    If ( $kArray["responseEnvelope.ack"] == "Success") 
    {

        foreach ($kArray as $key =>$value){
            echo $key . ": " .$value . "<br/>";
        }
    }
    else {
        echo 'ERROR Code: ' .  $kArray["error(0).errorId"] . " <br/>";
        echo 'ERROR Message: ' .  urldecode($kArray["error(0).message"]) . " <br/>";
    }
}


catch(Exception $e) 
{
    echo "Message: ||" .$e->getMessage()."||";
}

//End check paykey

?>
```

I would have attached an image showing all of the fields that you can get at with $kArray but I don't have the reputation. you would want: $kArray["paymentInfoList.paymentInfo(0).transactionId"]

**NOTE: the API credentials you should use for sandbox can be found under your "sandbox accounts" at developer.paypal.com. Expand the profile of xxxfacilitator@xxx to get them**

Comment: I am working in android and integrated paypal using Android sdk. I got the paykey but now i would like to get the transactionId of it. You are using php code to get it and also passing user credentials but i don't have user credentials then how can i get those details using pay key only? Do u have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

We can get transaction details like -

First get access token using your clientId and ClientSecret

```
$ch = curl_init();
            $clientId = PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID; //client Id
            $secret = PAYPAL_CLIENT_SECRET; client secrete key
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token");
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $clientId . ":" . $secret);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "grant_type=client_credentials");
            $result = curl_exec($ch);
            $accessToken = null;
            if (empty($result))
               die('invalid access token');
            else {
                $json = json_decode($result);
                $accessToken = $json->access_token;
            }
            curl_close($ch);
```

After Getting access token, I get transaction detail using following code

```
 $curl = curl_init("https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/<paykey>");
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, false);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                'Authorization: Bearer ' . $accessToken,
                'Accept: application/json',
                'Content-Type: application/json'
            ));
            $response = curl_exec($curl);
            $result = json_decode($response);
```

With this we can validate transaction.

remove sandbox work from url when you are using it for live.